# Insert into every row of a collection a new item LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How i can achieve this not using a loop & array and rather use a collection ?

I have a collection witch i create this way

```
  $datas = collect($xml_datas['data']);
```

The collection format look like this :

```
[

{
    "reference": "3437247",
    "numero_mandat": "4536",
    "type_mandat": "simple",
    "operation": "vente",
    "type": "Bureau ",
    "adresse": "Boulevard du chine ",
    "code_postal": "34000",
    "ville": "MONTPELLIER",
    "prix": "400000",
    "honoraire_agence": "0",
    "honoraire_frais_dossier": "0",
    "pourcentage_honoraire_acquereur": "5.26",
    "taxe_fonciere": "0.000000",
    "charges_mensuelles": "0",
    "surf_habitable": "180",
    "depot_garantie": null,
    "nombre_piece": "9",
    "annee_construction": "1977",
    "loyer_mensuel_occupant": "0.00"
},
{
    "reference": "3437271",
    "numero_mandat": "6125",
    "type_mandat": "simple",
    "operation": "vente",
    "type": "Maison de caractère",
    "adresse": "5 rue de l'égalité",
    "code_postal": "34800",
    "ville": "PERET",
    "prix": "803000",
    "honoraire_agence": "0",
    "honoraire_frais_dossier": "0",
    "pourcentage_honoraire_acquereur": "0",
    "taxe_fonciere": "2000.000000",
    "charges_mensuelles": "0",
    "surf_habitable": "210",
    "depot_garantie": null,
    "nombre_piece": "7",
    "annee_construction": "2000",
    "loyer_mensuel_occupant": "0.00"
},
```

And i wanna add 3 new item into every row of the collection (those value are the same), for ex this collection have 350 Items of different real estate property, i wanna add into ALL those 350 Items those data

```
       'software' => 'adaptimmo',
       'user_id' =>Auth::user()->id,
       'slug_import' => 'SomeRandom',
```

So that my collection **end up like this**

```
[

{
    "software": "adaptimmo", // <--- We added
    "user_id": "1",
    "slug_import": "SomeRandom",
    "reference": "3437247",
    "numero_mandat": "4536",
    "type_mandat": "simple",
    "operation": "vente",
    "type": "Bureau ",
    "adresse": "Boulevard du chine ",
    "code_postal": "34000",
    "ville": "MONTPELLIER",
    "prix": "400000",
    "honoraire_agence": "0",
    "honoraire_frais_dossier": "0",
    "pourcentage_honoraire_acquereur": "5.26",
    "taxe_fonciere": "0.000000",
    "charges_mensuelles": "0",
    "surf_habitable": "180",
    "depot_garantie": null,
    "nombre_piece": "9",
    "annee_construction": "1977",
    "loyer_mensuel_occupant": "0.00"
},
{
    "software": "adaptimmo",
    "user_id": "1",
    "slug_import": "SomeRandom",
    "reference": "3437271",
    "numero_mandat": "6125",
    "type_mandat": "simple",
    "operation": "vente",
    "type": "Maison de caractère",
    "adresse": "5 rue de l'égalité",
    "code_postal": "34800",
    "ville": "PERET",
    "prix": "803000",
    "honoraire_agence": "0",
    "honoraire_frais_dossier": "0",
    "pourcentage_honoraire_acquereur": "0",
    "taxe_fonciere": "2000.000000",
    "charges_mensuelles": "0",
    "surf_habitable": "210",
    "depot_garantie": null,
    "nombre_piece": "7",
    "annee_construction": "2000",
    "loyer_mensuel_occupant": "0.00"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous methods available on collections documented here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#available-methods

You’re probably looking for the `each()` method:

```php
$items = collect($xml_datas['data'])->each(function ($item) {
    // Add new keys to the item
    $item->software = 'adaptimmo';
    $item->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $item->slug_import = 'SomeRandom';
});
```

Comment: Okey just tried i think you right its the way to do it but i have a new problem now, overall from what i understood a collection doesn't change the 'format' of what you give, and thus, since the datas i have are Array, i can't use ->each $item->software , i got a error about not being a Object. How i can work around that ?

Comment: Use array syntax instead of it’s an array: `$item['software'] = 'adaptimmo'` etc.